# emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP

Tags: android, android-emulator

**Why am I getting the Classic qemu warning?**

- Android Studio Version 2.1.2 (from stable channel)
- Android 4.3.1 (API 18)
- Emulator Version: I don't know
- Android SDK Tools: 25.1.7
- Host Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
- Processor : AMD A8-5600K APU with Randeon(tm) HD Graphics 3.60 GHz

This is an example of what appears when I run an emulator:

C:\Users\soda\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd gaby_API_18

**emulator: WARNING:** Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.

emulator: warning: opening audio input failed

Comment: Why downvote? its a VALID question..

Answer (score 0):

I get the same behaviour when I run the API 18 image. I guess this image only runs under classic QEMU rather than QEMU2. So far it seems to me that only API 19 and higher use QEMU2.

It seems that something is setting "hw.cpu.ncore" to 2 in hardware-qemu.ini for the emulator image. You might be able to remove the warning by removing that line from the file. However, I don't think the warning is doing much harm.